# echo program prints newline instead of '\n'

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

In bash, anything between single quotes will remain its literal meaning, but when I type "echo '\n'" in my terminal. The output I get is a newline instead of the expected '\n' character.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/cLGRaN)

Comment: Please double check that you are using bash and not `zsh` or some other shell.

Comment: You can't figure it out with `echo $SHELL`

Comment: @GillesQuenot: Note that `$SHELL` can contain the login shell, not the currently running shell.

Comment: Which is why you **can't** figure it out that way, yes

Comment: What's the difference between zsh shell or bash, I am using zsh shell on my macos.

Comment: 'I am using zsh shell on my macos'. You shouldn't have tagged this question either [linux] or [bash], then. I cleaned up the tags, but remember to use appropriate ones in the future.

Comment: @Nin : It's similar as the difference between C++ and Java: They are different programming languages, but they have similarities. If you know one, you have a much easier time learning the other.

Answer (score 4):

According to the POSIX spec for `echo`:

> If the first operand is -n, or if any of the operands contain a `<backslash>` character, the results are implementation-defined.

`echo` is normally a shell builtin, and `zsh`'s will interpret backlash escapes by default. You can use `echo -E`, which tells both the `zsh` and `bash` versions of `echo` to disable treating them specially. `zsh` also uses the `BSD_ECHO` shell option to control this behavior:

```
$ echo "\n"

$ echo -E "\n"
\n
$ setopt BSD_ECHO
$ echo "\n"
\n
```

The most portable alternative, though, is using `printf` instead of `echo`, as it doesn't rely on any shell-specific behaviors:

```
$ printf '\\n\n'
\n
```

Comment: Seriously, just use `printf` anytime you want to reliably print anything that might contain backslash or start with "`-`", or are tempted to use any of `echo`'s options (i.e. `-n` or `-e`). `echo` implementations are just to inconsistent to use for anything nontrivial.

Answer (score 0):

Checked this using bash and zsh under macos Catalina.

- bash: $echo '\n’ produced "\n"
- zsh: %echo '\n' produced newline
- zsh: %echo '\n' produces "\n"